# OAuth 2.0 (or similar) without security token

Tags: oauth2

[This article about oAuth 2.0](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&language=en) says , that user must provide security token to log in.
Can i somehow disable usage of security tokens? I don't want my users to perform unnecessary operation.

Or may be there is some alternative way to find out , if user's login\password are valid in salesforce

My code to authorize (may be there is another issue why i have an error like

**{"error_description":"expired access/refresh token","error":"invalid_grant"}**  )

```
    private const string ClientId = "3MVG9A2kN3Bn17huRprJBCInrodPdsyHERlP1nUDPXnApOiQURGxtr9pxl...."; // Consumer Key from SFDC account
    private const string ClientSecret = "43802039754906815..."; // Consumer Secret from SFDC account
    private const string RedirectUrl = "https://localhost:8443/...."; // Redirect URL configured in SFDC account
    private const string  SfOAuthUrl = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token";

public static void AuthenticateToSalesforce()
    {
        var username = "myMail@gmail.com";
        var password = "MyPassword_Without_Security toke";

        var parameters = "grant_type=password"
                                  + "&client_id=" + ClientId
                                  + "&client_secret=" + ClientSecret
                                  + "&redirect_uri=" + RedirectUrl
                                  + "&username=" + username
                                  + "&password=" + password;

        var result = HttpPost(@SfOAuthUrl, @parameters);
    }

    public static string HttpPost(string URI, string Parameters)
    {
        var req = WebRequest.Create(URI);
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";

        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Parameters);
        req.ContentLength = data.Length;
        var os = req.GetRequestStream();
        os.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        os.Close();

        try
        {
            var resp = req.GetResponse();
            var sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            var resp = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(resp);
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

I've also set the range of trusted IPs which, according to the article, should disable usage of security tokens, but error is still the same

Comment: I suggest that you get your code working using the password and security token first as it is very easy to get the parameter encoding and other aspects of the code wrong and confuse one problem with another problem. But I do recollect being able to leave out the security token when I had "IP Restrictions" set to "Relax IP restrictions" but have since changed to using one of the other OATH flows. I am unsure of the security pros/cons.

Answer (score 3):

Security Tokens are not required from Trusted IP addresses.

You can make a single range of IP address 'trusted' in Setup > Security Controls > Network Access.

You can blat out multiple ranges like 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 (not recommended) on a Profile too.

Keith C's commentary is well placed; holding user credentials (and security token) may be a red flag.

[image: profile ip range]

Comment: I tried the question code out with some test user credentials where my IP was trusted. It worked fine without the security token.

Comment: Note that I don't think you can block out the entire list of IPV4 addresses in one go. You need to do it in smaller ranges.

Comment: They blocked that a few releases ago, yes.

Comment: @DanielBallinger perhaps not for the best, but from any `Profile` under `Login IP Ranges` the entire IPV4 space can indeed be trusted, obviating security tokens (Winter '14)

Comment: @user320 Interesting. I once had to make a tool to block out all the IP ranges for a testing org (long story). Good to know it can be done in a straight forward manner.

Comment: By the way, salesforce does not allow me to set range from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 in the menu, that user320 had said about. An error says "The range specified is too large"

Comment: It is strange : even after setting an IP range i still have the same error. Ok, can you please clarify, 
if I have made all correctly : 
1) Setup => Create => APP , New Connected App
1.1) Set checkbox 'Enable oAuth' in API (Enable OAuth Settings) frame, input any url, provide full access

2)Insert this app's client id and secret into my programm
3)Insert my salesforce login and password

Did i miss some steps ?

Comment: @Ban, check your Login History. `Setup > Administer > Manage Users > Login History`. Do your login attempts appear there? If they do they should include your IP address as Salesforce sees it. This is what you need to grant as a Trusted IP (assuming you have a static IP).

Comment: Thnank you for reply. I can see my login attempts from web browser, but not from console application

Answer (score 2):

The token's only required if you use *user/pass* flow, which is *not recommended* for normal, production-ready OAuth2 implementations (it's the same as trying to make a SOAP login() call). Instead, use the *user-client* flow, which follows the normal Identity Confirmation flow (e.g. a SMS or email verification code). In C#, for example, you can use a WebBrowser control to present the OAuth2 login. If the user's default browser is Internet Explorer, *and* they are already logged in through another window, *and* they've already granted access, the login will complete automatically with no interaction from the user at all.